# Did Loefller or other any other senator sign the objection to Georgia's certificate and then withdraw it, or did they not sign it in the first place?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, senate, joe-biden

The objections to Georgia, Michigan, Nevada certificates were only signed by members of the House of Representatives, but by no Senator, unlike those regarding Arizona and Pennsylvania.

The objection to Georgia's certificate was said (when it was raised in the joint session) to have been [intended do be] signed by some Senator(s), but Senator Loeffler (previously) said on the floor that following the Trump supporters' breaking into the Congress floor (and offices) she's no longer objecting.

I'm confused about this because I've only seen it discussed on live TV, so I'm unclear on the details. Did some Senator sign the objection to Georgia's certificate, but then got their signature "stricken", either physically or just verbally? Or did they not actually sign the objection, i.e. were they waiting until the last moment to do so and changed their mind before actually, physically signing?

Answer (score 9):

Senators Kelly Loeffler (R-Ga.), Mike Braun (R-Ind.), Steve Daines (R-Mont.) and James Lankford (R-Okla.) "abandoned plans" to make objections to Biden electors. I read it as they never signed it.

In his speech, Senator Mitt Romney said that they "withdrawn" their objection:

> “I salute Senator Lankford and Loeffler and Braun and Danes and I’m sure others, who in the light of today’s outrage have withdrawn their objection” — [New York Post](https://nypost.com/2021/01/06/romney-slams-trump-as-selfish-man-praises-gop-who-dropped-objections/), [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ms2bjq_5sN0)

Comment: "Withdrawn" was also stated by the Congressman who raised the objection when the VP asked if it was in writing and signed by a Rep and a Senator. He made it sound like they had signed then withdrew, but I was watching late at night and Congressional Record for yesterday is not out yet.